# Converting byte[] to float[]

Tags: android, floatbuffer

I'm trying to convert a float[] to a byte[] in Android. I've looked at other questions and answers on stackoverflow but none of them helped so I decided to implement my own solution. The way I have tried is:

```
byte[] data = some data;
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length);
buffer.put(data);
FloatBuffer fBuffer = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
float[] dataConverted = fBuffer.array();
```

However, the exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.nio.ByteBufferAsFloatBuffer.protectedArray(ByteBufferAsFloatBuffer.java:128)
    at java.nio.FloatBuffer.array(FloatBuffer.java:101)
```

From the line:

```
    float[] dataConverted = fBuffer.array();
```

Keeps being thrown, and I'm not sure why. Could someone help explain why this exception is being thrown; it would be of great help?

Comment: that's not how it works. read asFloatBuffer documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FloatBuffer allocated does not have a backing array to return; please refer to [FloatBuffer.hasArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html#hasArray%28%29). To achieve the effect that you would like, try copying the FloatBuffer to a float array via [FloatBuffer.get(float[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html#get%28float%5b%5d%29)

Sample code:

```
final byte[] data = new byte[] {
        64, 73, 15, -48, 127, 127, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
};

final FloatBuffer fb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).asFloatBuffer();
final float[] dst = new float[fb.capacity()];
fb.get(dst); // Copy the contents of the FloatBuffer into dst

for (int i = 0; i < dst.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(dst[i]);
    if (i == dst.length - 1) {
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3.14159, 3.4028235E38, 1.4E-45, 0.0
```